# Send File via socket in java

Tags: java, file, sockets

I've a client and a server. The server maintains a File and the client does a request for it.
So, what I do is

```
File CONFIGURATION_FILE=new File(configuration.doc);
System.out.println (CONFIGURATION_FILE.exist()); //return true

in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
oos=new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

String line;
while ((line=in.readLine())!=null) {

  if (line.equals("configuration file"))
        oos.writeObject(CONFIGURATION_FILE);
        oos.flush();
  }
}
```

When I receive on the client the File, it throws an IOException. The program works if I pass the absolute path when I create the File (client and server are on the same machine for the moment, so I think that what is passed through the socket is a reference to the path and both the client and the server can see that). My question is: Is possible sending a File as an Object through the socket channel directly or I must convert it to an array of bytes and send this array? Thank you in advance

Comment: The File object is an `"abstract representation of file and directory pathnames"` (javadoc). So no, you can't just send it through a socket. You can hovewer use NIO to simplify the handling of the streams.

Comment: `File` really should have been called `Path`, but it's too late for them to fix it now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert it to bytes and send bytes. For example your Server may have the file in `F:/Out.txt` so if you send the actual file object to a client, the client might not have a `F:` drive at all. Furthermore the File class makes use of a lot native methods. Serializing and De-serializing it is never a good idea.